# Phaser Javascript Spinning Wheel auto spin issue

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am having problem trying to make a spinning wheel spin automatically on page load and also display multiple wheels on the same page.  The spinner is based on Phaser.  I am not a JavaScript nor Phaser programmer so your assistance is appreciated. This is probably something simple to do.

Here is the game.js code for the spinning wheel.  (The complete spinning wheel script can be downloaded [here](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/05/22/build-a-wheel-of-fortune-for-your-html5-games-with-phaser-in-only-a-few-lines-updated-to-phaser-3-8-0/))

```
// the game itself
var game;
 
var gameOptions = {
 
    // slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
    slices: 8,
 
    // prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
    slicePrizes: ["A KEY!!!", "50 STARS", "500 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!", "200 STARS", "100 STARS", "150 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!"],
 
    // wheel rotation duration, in milliseconds
    rotationTime: 3000
}
 
// once the window loads...
window.onload = function() {
 
    // game configuration object
    var gameConfig = {
 
        // render type
       type: Phaser.CANVAS,
 
       // game width, in pixels
       width: 550,
 
       // game height, in pixels
       height: 550,
 
       // game background color
       backgroundColor: 0x880044,
 
       // scenes used by the game
       scene: [playGame]
    };
 
    // game constructor
    game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
 
    // pure javascript to give focus to the page/frame and scale the game
    window.focus()
    resize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
}
 
// PlayGame scene
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene{
 
    // constructor
    constructor(){
        super("PlayGame");
    }
 
    // method to be executed when the scene preloads
    preload(){
 
        // loading assets
        this.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
        this.load.image("pin", "pin.png");
    }
 
    // method to be executed once the scene has been created
    create(){
 
        // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
        this.wheel = this.add.sprite(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height / 2, "wheel");
 
        // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
        this.pin = this.add.sprite(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height / 2, "pin");
 
        // adding the text field
        this.prizeText = this.add.text(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height - 20, "Spin the wheel", {
            font: "bold 32px Arial",
            align: "center",
            color: "white"
        });
 
        // center the text
        this.prizeText.setOrigin(0.5);
 
        // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
        this.canSpin = true;
 
        // waiting for your input, then calling "spinWheel" function
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.spinWheel, this);
    }
 
    // function to spin the wheel
    spinWheel(){
 
        // can we spin the wheel?
        if(this.canSpin){
 
            // resetting text field
            this.prizeText.setText("");
 
            // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
            var rounds = Phaser.Math.Between(2, 4);
 
            // then will rotate by a random number from 0 to 360 degrees. This is the actual spin
            var degrees = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 360);
 
            // before the wheel ends spinning, we already know the prize according to "degrees" rotation and the number of slices
            var prize = gameOptions.slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / gameOptions.slices));
 
            // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
            this.canSpin = false;
 
            // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
            // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
            this.tweens.add({
 
                // adding the wheel to tween targets
                targets: [this.wheel],
 
                // angle destination
                angle: 360 * rounds + degrees,
 
                // tween duration
                duration: gameOptions.rotationTime,
 
                // tween easing
                ease: "Cubic.easeOut",
 
                // callback scope
                callbackScope: this,
 
                // function to be executed once the tween has been completed
                onComplete: function(tween){
 
                    // displaying prize text
                    this.prizeText.setText(gameOptions.slicePrizes[prize]);
 
                    // player can spin again
                    this.canSpin = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
 
// pure javascript to scale the game
function resize() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowRatio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
    var gameRatio = game.config.width / game.config.height;
    if(windowRatio < gameRatio){
        canvas.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
        canvas.style.height = (windowWidth / gameRatio) + "px";
    }
    else{
        canvas.style.width = (windowHeight * gameRatio) + "px";
        canvas.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it so that

1. it will start spinning as soon as the page is loaded.
2. place more than one wheel on a page.  When I call the JavaScript twice, it does not display two wheels.  The purpose of this exercise is to feed the wheel with two different "degrees" so that it can display the two results.  The alternative will be to spin the wheel twice.  After the first spin, display the first result and spin again to display the second result.  But this is probably harder to do than simply display two wheels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question , *'...spinning as soon as page is loaded..'*, the answer is:

- just add the code line `this.spinWheel();` at the end of the `create` function, this will start it right away.

For the second part:

- just add in the `gameConfig` - object the property `parent`, with an id of an html-tag
- create a game instance *(no action needed)*
- than copy and past the whole `gameConfig`
- change the `parent`, to a different tag-id
- create a second game instance. *( add the line `game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);`)*

**Here a short Demo showcasing, these two fixes:**
*(depending on your exact goal, and what you want to achieve, there might be better ways to solve this)*

> ***FYI:***
>
> - Images are not loaded, because they won't work here, but one can see how the auto spinning would work.
> - I remove code that was not so relevant for the demo, so that it can be understund more easy.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var gameOptions = {
    slices: 8,
    slicePrizes: ["A KEY!!!", "50 STARS", "500 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!", "200 STARS", "100 STARS", "150 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!"],
    rotationTime: 3000
}
  
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene{
 
    constructor(){
        super("PlayGame");
    }
 
    preload(){
        //this.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
        //this.load.image("pin", "pin.png");
    }
 
    create(){
 
        this.wheel = this.add.sprite(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height / 2, "wheel");
        this.pin = this.add.sprite(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height / 2, "pin");
 
        this.prizeText = this.add.text(game.config.width / 2, game.config.height - 20, "Spin the wheel", {
            font: "bold 32px Arial",
            align: "center",
            color: "white"
        });
 
        this.prizeText.setOrigin(0.5);
 
        this.canSpin = true;
 
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.spinWheel, this);
        
        this.spinWheel();
    }
 
     spinWheel(){
        if(this.canSpin){
            this.prizeText.setText("");
            var rounds = Phaser.Math.Between(2, 4);
            var degrees = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 360);
            var prize = gameOptions.slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / gameOptions.slices));
            this.canSpin = false;

            this.tweens.add({
                targets: [this.wheel],
                angle: 360 * rounds + degrees,
                duration: gameOptions.rotationTime,
                ease: "Cubic.easeOut",
                callbackScope: this,
                onComplete: function(tween){
                    this.prizeText.setText(gameOptions.slicePrizes[prize]);
                    this.canSpin = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

var gameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    parent: 'wheel1',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 0x880044,
    scene: [playGame]
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);

gameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    parent: 'wheel2',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    // I altered also the background color to show the difference
    backgroundColor: 0x0ff044,
    scene: [playGame]
};

game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
```

```css
 #wheel1, #wheel2, canvas{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>

<div id="wheel1"></div><div id="wheel2"></div>
```

***Updated* - Update:**

The main problem is that I made a mistake, the property is not `parentElement` it is `parent`. I tried to fix this in following demo.

```js
// the game itself
var game;

var gameOptions = {

    // slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
    slices: 8,

    // prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
    // this array has to contain atleast 8 value
    slicePrizes: ["A KEY!!!", "50 STARS", "500 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!", "200 STARS", "100 STARS", "150 STARS", "BAD LUCK!!!"],

    // wheel rotation duration, in milliseconds
    rotationTime: 3000
}

var gameConfig;
// once the window loads...
window.onload = function () {

    gameConfig = {
        type: Phaser.CANVAS,
        parent: 'wheel1',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 0x880044,
        scene: [playGame]
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    game.scene.start('PlayGame', { degrees: 60 });

    gameConfig = {
        type: Phaser.CANVAS,
        parent: 'wheel2',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        // I altered also the background color to show the difference
        backgroundColor: 0x0ff044,
        scene: [playGame]
    };

    var game2 = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    game2.scene.start('PlayGame', { degrees: 40 });

    window.focus()
    resize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
}

// PlayGame scene
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene {

    // constructor
    constructor() {
        super({ key: "PlayGame" });
    }

    // method to be executed when the scene preloads
    preload() {

        // loading assets
        //this.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
        //this.load.image("pin", "pin.png");
    }

    // method to be executed once the scene has been created
    create(data) {

        // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
        this.wheel = this.add.sprite(gameConfig.width / 2, gameConfig.height / 2, "wheel");

        // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
        this.pin = this.add.sprite(gameConfig.width / 2, gameConfig.height / 2, "pin");

        // adding the text field
        this.prizeText = this.add.text(gameConfig.width / 2, gameConfig.height - 20, "Spin the wheel", {
            font: "bold 32px Arial",
            align: "center",
            color: "black"
        });

        // center the text
        this.prizeText.setOrigin(0.5);

        // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
        this.canSpin = true;

        //this.input.on("pointerdown", this.spinWheel, this);
        this.spinWheel(data.degrees);
    }

    // function to spin the wheel
    spinWheel(degrees) {

        // can we spin the wheel?
        if (this.canSpin) {

            // resetting text field
            this.prizeText.setText("");

            // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
            var rounds = Phaser.Math.Between(8, 10);

            //var degrees = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 360);
            var prize = gameOptions.slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / gameOptions.slices));

            // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
            this.canSpin = false;

            // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
            // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
            this.tweens.add({

                // adding the wheel to tween targets
                targets: [this.wheel],

                // angle destination
                angle: 360 * rounds + degrees,

                // tween duration
                duration: gameOptions.rotationTime,

                // tween easing
                ease: "Cubic.easeOut",

                // callback scope
                callbackScope: this,

                // function to be executed once the tween has been completed
                onComplete: function (tween) {

                    // displaying prize text
                    this.prizeText.setText(gameOptions.slicePrizes[prize]);

                    // player can spin again
                    this.canSpin = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

// pure javascript to scale the game
function resize() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#wheels");
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowRatio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
    var gameRatio = gameConfig.width / gameConfig.height;

    if (windowRatio < gameRatio) {
        canvas.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
        //canvas.style.height = (windowWidth / gameRatio) + "px";
    }
    else {
        canvas.style.width = (windowHeight * gameRatio) + "px";
        //canvas.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    }

}
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wheels{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    align-items: stretch;
}    

#wheel1, #wheel2, canvas{
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 

canvas{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>

<div id="wheels">
  <div id="wheel1"></div>
  <div id="wheel2"></div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The auto spinning is working.  But I could not get the second part to work.  I am showing the whole html above.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: My goal is to display my 4-6 results using the spinning wheel.  Not sure what you mean by another way of doing it?

Comment: @Jack I update my answer the problem was I told you the wrong property it was not `parentElement`,  but `parent`. I reposted the code I hope this woeks for you, you would probably need to improve the css, since I'm no CSS expert.

Comment: btw.: when I wrote _"...another way of doing it..." I mean, there are many ways of solving the problem, depending on what you need, my solution could be optimal or there might be a better way. It was only a disclaimer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @winner_joiner Not sure what happened.  When I did the same I only see a blank page.  The test page is set up here https://realsidualincome.com/test.html  If I replace the js from the cdn with <script src = "phaser.min.js"></script> I get the color boxes only, lol.

Comment: @Jack if you check the browser console, one can see that it seems to be a problem with the line `slicePrizes: ["A","B","C","D,"E","F","G"],` There is a quote missing after the `"D`, just add the missing quote and it should work.

Comment: I wish it was that but it still won't work.  I do see color boxes, lol.   It is complaining about the game.config.  Either game.config or gameconfig still won't show the wheels.  I am wondering if it has something to do with the images.

Comment: in the `resize` function it compare my demo code with yours. it should be `gameConfig` not `game.config`. I hope this helps

Comment: I changed it to gameconfig in both resize and create function.  But same error.  Now it is complaining about gameconfig, lol

Comment: @Jack you have to copy the  words/commands very precise `gameConfig` with upper Case **"C"**.

Comment: Thanks, @winner_joiner The two wheels can now be displayed on the page.  However, because these wheels will be used for display purpose, I need to pass two values to the "degrees" variable. e.g. 45 and 90 so that the two wheels will display them accordingly.  This was part of my original question.  Currently, it will only display two random results.

Comment: @Jack I updated the last Demo, to cover the set degree option, in my answer. It is a minor fix.

Comment: Thanks @winner_joiner it seems to work almost.., except the second wheel is not showing a value. :(   https://realsidualincome.com/test.html

Comment: @Jack well the problem is, that there are 8 slices on the wheel, but you have only 7, values in the `slicePrizes` Array(in the `gameOption` object). If no value for the given Slice can befound, no value will be displayed. _As mentioned earlier precision is key in programming._

Comment: when I tried to add more wheels so that I can have 5 across the screen.  The wheels became very small.  Any way to fix that so they can all fit the width of the browser?

Comment: @Jack as mentioned before I'm no CSS expert, but I would remove the `resize` function, and just set the width of the `#wheels` div in the css to `width:100%` in the css. if this doesnt work for you, I would suggest posting a new question, mentioning/ describing only this sizing issue (aka using the `css` and `html` tag).

Comment: Thank you so much @winner_joiner !  They are now bigger.  You still have way more knowledge in CSS than me, lol.   Now just have to figure out how to reduce the spaces between the wheels so they can be even larger. :)

Comment: are you able to help with the spacing issue?  I try to avoid creating another question just on this. :)

Comment: @Jack well I guess you could set the `margin:5px` or so on the `#wheel1, #wheel2, ..., canvas`, but I'm not sure if this will work for multiple wheels.

Comment: currently it is already set at margin: 0.  5px will make it even wider.  I am not sure how the margin was set, automatically?

Comment: @Jack as i'm no css expert, just ask a new question only tagged with css and html, add the relevant code (only ` css` and `html`) and you will surely get an answer in minutes.